# getline() in C++ - _GNU_SOURCE not needed?

Tags: c++, getline

Firstly, I'm pretty new to C++. I believe that `getline()` isn't a standard C function, so `#define _GNU_SOURCE` is required to use it. I'm now using C++ and g++ tells me that `_GNU_SOURCE` is already defined:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Werror parser.cpp
parser.cpp:1:1: error: "_GNU_SOURCE" redefined
<command-line>: error: this is the location of the previous definition
```

Can anyone confirm if this is standard, or is its definition hidden somewhere in my setup? I'm not sure of the meaning of the final line quoted.

The file's includes are as follows, so presumably it's defined in one or more of these?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think g++, from version 3, automagically defines `_GNU_SOURCE`.  This is supported by your third line in the error stating that the first definition was done on the command line (with nary a `-D_GNU_SOURCE` in sight):

```
<command-line>: error: this is the location of the previous definition
```

If you don't want it, `#undef` it as the first line in your compilation unit. You may need it, however, in which case use:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
    #define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
```

The reason you're getting the error is because you're re-defining it. It shouldn't be an error if you define it to what it already was. At least that's the case with C, it may be different with C++. Based on the GNU headers, I would say they're doing an implicit `-D_GNU_SOURCE=1` which is why it thinks you're *re-defining* it to something else.

The following snippet should tell you its value provided you haven't changed it.

```
#define DBG(x) printf ("_GNU_SOURCE = [" #x "]\n")
DBG(_GNU_SOURCE); // first line in main.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, cleared things up for me. I'll use the preprocessor as suggested for compatibility.

Comment: The two-line snippet at the end is not quite right: you need an extra level of macro expansion. The three-line snippet `(1) #define STRINGIZE(x) #x (2) #define DBG(x) printf (#x"=["STRINGIZE(x)"]\n") (3) DBG(_GNU_SOURCE);` gives me: `_GNU_SOURCE=[1]`

Comment: And, speaking more generally, `DBG(x)` should perhaps be #define'd as `printf("%s\n", ...etc...)`, to handle the remote possibility that `#x` contains a `%`.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had to use one of the following in C++.  Never had to declare _GNU_ anything before.  I usually run in *nix so I usually use gcc and g++ as well.

```
string s = cin.getline()

char c;
cin.getchar(&c);
```

Comment: He means this getline: http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Line-Input.html

Answer (score 0):

Getline is standard it is defined in two ways.
You can call it as a member function of one of streams as follows:
This is the version defined in

```
//the first parameter is the cstring to accept the data
//the second parameter is the maximum number of characters to read
//(including the terminating null character)
//the final parameter is an optional delimeter character that is by default '\n'
char buffer[100];
std::cin.getline(buffer, 100, '\n');
```

or you can use the version defined in

```
//the first parameter is the stream to retrieve the data from
//the second parameter is the string to accept the data
//the third parameter is the delimeter character that is by default set to '\n'
std::string buffer;
std::getline(std::cin, buffer,'\n');
```

for further reference
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline.html
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline.html